# WordPress add_action inside a class with methods callbacks

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I created a custom plugin.
What I try to do is to put inside a class "Hooks" create methods for add_actions with a callback parameter.

The reason I am to that is to call easy a WP hook and to store all WP hooks in one file and not repeat add_actions in a code.

How can I do this correctly? Now the admin_notice don't display.

```
namespace Classes;
if( ! defined ('ABSPATH')){ die;} // when user try to direct access the file

class Hooks
{
private $_notice;
private $_wploaded;
private $_init;
private $_Class;


//admin_notices Prints admin screen notices.

public function admin_notices($Class,$call){
$this->_notice = $call;
$this->_Class = $Class;
add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this->_Class, $this->_notice ) );
}

//wp_loaded After WordPress is fully loaded

protected function wp_loaded($call){
$this->_wploaded = $call;
 add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, $this->_wploaded ) );
}

//init

 protected function init($call){
  $this->_init = $call;
   add_action( 'init', array( $this, $this->_init ) );
  }

}
```

Then another class

```
namespace Classes;

if( ! defined ('ABSPATH')){ die;} // when user try to direct access the file

class Core
{
 public  $TypeNotice;
 public  $message;

 // get Message

    public function set_Message( $message ){
        $this->message = $message;
      }

    // show admin notice based on get Message method

     public function show_Message($TypeNotice){
       $this->TypeNotice = $TypeNotice;
       $Hooks = new Classes\Hooks();
       switch ($this->TypeNotice) {
         case 'Error':
           return $Hooks->admin_notices("Classes\Core","show_Message") . '<div class="error notice is-dismissable"><p>'.$this->message.'</p></div>';
           break;

         default:
           return $Hooks->admin_notices("Classes\Core","show_Message") . '<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible"><p>'.$this->message.'</p></div>';
           break;
       }


     }
}

  $plugin = new Classes\Core();
  $plugin->set_Message("Hi");
  $plugin->show_Message("Error");
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes, i changed the post

Comment: The `show_message` call is returning HTML `<div class="error notice is-dismissable"><p>Hi</p></div>`. The `$Hooks->admin_notices($this,"show_Message");` line is never reached. Also, the object `$Hooks` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the code but still not working. I got this Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'show_Message' not found

Comment: Check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#user-contributed-notes for referance on the `add_action` in class

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to do better!

```
class Notices
{
private $_admin_notice = "admin_notices"; // name of action
private $_message;

// 1. get Message
public function set_Message( $message ){
$this->_message = $message;
}

// 2. define add_action admin notices for method error
public function show_Error(){
add_action( $this->_admin_notice, array( $this, 'set_error_Message') );
}

// 2a. define add_action admin notices for method notice
public function show_Notice(){
add_action( $this->_admin_notice, array( $this, 'set_notice_Message') );
}

// 2b. define add_action admin notices for method notice
public function show_Warning(){
add_action( $this->_admin_notice, array( $this, 'set_warning_Message') );
}

// 3. show admin error based on get Message method
public function set_error_Message(){
echo '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissable"><p>' . $this->_message . '</p> </div>';
}
// 3a. show admin notice based on get Message method
public function set_notice_Message(){
echo '<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible"><p>' . $this->_message . '</p></div>';
}
// 3b. show admin warning based on get Message method
public function set_warning_Message(){
echo '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><p>' . $this->_message . '</p></div>';
}

}
```

Then initialization the class

```
  $notice = new Notices();
  $notice->set_Message("Hi");
  $notice->show_Notice();
```